# Is it possible to use regex as textinputformat delimiter with JavaSparkContext?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I have multiple text files to read with JavaSparkContext, and each of the file might be slightly different and contains multiline records, so I want to use a regex delimiter to find the records. Is it possible to configure the textinputformat delimiter with a regex?

```
..
String regex = "^(?!(^a\\s|^b\\s))";
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", regex);
..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not. `textinputformat.record.delimiter` has to be a fix pattern. When working with Spark, you have to alternatives:

- Implement your own Hadoop input format - scales better but requires more work.
- Use `wholeTextFiles` (or `binaryFiles`) and split strings using regex - easy to use, but doesn't scale to large files.